# How can I find out the path of an icon used by a folder?

Tags: nautilus

I would like to find out the path of the icon used for the below folder in Nautilus file manager.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your icon theme. It's usually
`/path/to/your/icon/theme/directory/places/xx/folder.svg` (or .png)
or
`/path/to/your/icon/theme/directory/xx/places/folder.svg` 
(`xx` stands for various sizes).

Icon theme directories are usually located at `/usr/share/icons/` (system-wide) or `~/.icons/` (local) or `~/.local/share/icons/` (local).

From your screenshot it seems you're using Adwaita icon theme. In that case you should find the icon in `/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/xx/places/`.